# Sensible solutions to the removal of the offline_access permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, offline-mode

Am coming back to building a FB app after some time away from the FB Platform and I see that the old offline_access permission has been removed and replaced with long(ish)-expiry tokens[1].

So, it now seems like any external app that needs to push data to Facebook based on, say, a schedule or some activity in the external app will need to cope with that long-access token having expired. This is made more frustrating because now a user logging out of FB will also kill any long-expiry token[2], whereas before, offline_access lived on even when the user was logged out.

I'm still in the pondering-a-solution stage, but two ideas spring to mind:

1) Whenever my app contacts a user who has FB integration, they are requested to click a link that will trigger re-auth with FB to get a new long-access token. My users are generally contacted several times within the lifespan of a long-access token, so this *should* effectively keep renewing the long-access token for as long as they need (even if it does add some annoying friction to my app)

2) Because I can't guarantee that 1) will always work (due to users not clicking the re-auth link in my app's email notification or them logging out of Facebook, for example) I'll also have to handle failed FB interactions by placing them in a holding queue and emailing the user to explicitly ask them to grant a long-access token again. Not cool, but I see no other option. If they don't respond to the request after X attempts to ask them to re-grant permission, I'll just have to bin the task and email them to explain that it's due to an FB limitation, not my app. Again, not cool.

Has anyone had to come up with any better solutions to maintain the ability to interact with a user's account with authentication/explicit permissions? I'd be keen to hear what you did.

(This is all pending me re-reading the FB ToS, of course - it's entirely possible that this is against the rules, which would be even more frustrating)

EDIT/UPDATE: the data I need to push is images to a photo album which will arrive at my server from various sources and will then be pushed into an appropriate user's album (with their pre-granted permission, of course). I won't be able to guarantee having any web-based end-user interaction at the point in time the images hit my server in order to get the end user to grant me a new short-lifespan token. Basically, `offline_access` really would have been ideal for this IMO.

UPDATE 2: NB: it's really key to my use case that the user won't necessarily be using my app or Facebook when the token needs to be granted or extended.

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/
[2] http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right two options, but I will point out a third option and a little-known-fact that may or may not be relevant for your specific scenario of "needs to push data to Facebook"

First, another option available assuming you either have mobile web or canvas implemented for your app is app to user requests or notifications.  The user will get a little notification counter indicator next to your app name in the list of bookmarks.  If they respond to the request or the bookmark/notification counter gets them to hit your app, you can trigger your server-side token renewal/extension process.  This process is transparent to the user -- assuming they still have your app installed they see nothing.

Secondly, what a lot of people use offline_access for today is simply posting to the user's stream.  If that is all you need and you don't need to do a bunch of FQL queries or hit other actions on the graph API, then you don't actually need offline_access or a current user token if you get the publish_stream permission.  With publish_stream you can post while the user is offline by using your app access token.

Comment: I do need to do something more than just push to the stream - I want access to photo albums

Comment: OK then you are back to needing a way to get their attention so they will click through to your app.  Email and notifications/requests are your best hope.  Email will let you style your message and explain it better.  Requests give you very little text to work with.  I do both.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific "need to push data" scenario, [facebook announced](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/07/23/new-marketing-tools-for-pages/) new [Page object connections](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#unpub_scheduled_posts) that allow you to create post's with a specific publication time. With these in theory you can get rid of the problem by authenticating the users when creating these and let Facebook post them instead of scheduled jobs on your side.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but see my comment above - your solution is nice, but still requires the FB user to do something other than just grant a one-time permission to me.

Answer (score 1):

here comes 3rd option as a suggestion.

For each authenticated user, you have access_token and expires_in (assume that you have stored them in your db already)

1) Write a scheduled task, that checks existing tokens with their expires_in value
when you find any token close to expiration time,

2) you can renew this token from the server side by HTTP GET call (sample code below)

```
requestUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com" + "/oauth/access_token"
            + "?" + "client_id="+facebook_appId 
            + "&"+"client_secret="+facebook_appSecret
            + "&" + "grant_type=fb_exchange_token"
            + "&" + "fb_exchange_token="+currentToken;

            req = WS.url( requestUrl );
            Logger.info("renew token, req.url : %s", req.url);
            req.timeout = 20;
            resp = req.get();

            // access_token=....&expires=5181096
            Map<String, String> respMap = LocoUtils.decodeUrl( resp.getString() );
            token = respMap.containsKey("access_token")? respMap.get("access_token") : "";

            facebookToken.access_token = token;
            facebookToken.expires_in = respMap.containsKey("expires")?LocoUtils.stringToLong(respMap.get("expires")) : 0L;
```

Comment: that approach is coming from -> see scenario.4 under https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Thanks for this. Renewing a long-expiry token needs a short-expiry one, though -- I don't see a way to get hold of that short-expiry one without user action. Am I missing something?

Comment: short expiry token is given by default when user does OAuth with your facebook app_id

Comment: Yep, but I can't store that short-expiry token for longer than it lasts. So: short-expiry lets me get a long-expiry one. I track when the long one will die and, before then, get a new long-expiry token with which short-expiry token? The original short one will have expired, IIRC, so I'd have to ask the user to get me a new short one, no? Or can I used the stored OAuth credentials to act as the user and get a new short-expiry token?

Comment: when you get short-expiry token, refresh with long-expiry one then store in your db. this will make it 60 days by default. then you can follow the solution I suggested in answer above, to keep them always fresh. this should work

Comment: another way to validate the token is to call /me , if this returns user data, means token is still valid

Comment: Thanks WareNinja - the problem I have is that the FB docs say you need a short-expiry token to renew a long-expiry one. Is that not actually the case?

Comment: yes that's right. let me try to clarify further; when user autheticates, you get short-expiry by default, the sensible way is to refresh it in your backend with long-expiry one then store it, this will eliminate the first part of the problem.

Comment: btw. recently I struggled with similar problem, the solution i proposed is what i came up with for my apps