# why can't get user access token (offline) to manage pages?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to write a script to post to a page while the admin is offline.
my application has the manage_pages extended permission of the admin user.
here is my code:

```
require('php-sdk/src/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'MY_APP_ID', // YOUR APP ID
'secret' => 'MY_SECRET', // YOUR API SECRET
'cookie' => true
));

$user_admin_id = 'MY_ADMIN_ID';
$page_id = 'MY_PAGE_ID';

//get the access token to post to my page via the graph api
$accounts = $facebook->api("/" . $user_admin_id  . "/accounts");

foreach ($accounts['data'] as $account)
{
    if ($account['id'] == $page_id)
    {

    //found the access token, now we can break out of the loop
    $page_access_token = $account['access_token'];
    break;
    }
}
```

but I always get this message:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required
>   to request this resource. thrown in
>   /home/itrade10/public_html/khodiersoftware/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php
>   on line 1033"

Comment: The completely user interaction free `offline_access` permission have been removed from the facebook platform, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612067/sensible-solutions-to-the-removal-of-the-offline-access-permission) for workarounds. As it stands now, you can get tokens that live 60 days at most.

Comment: that´s not entirely correct, you can actually get forever living page access tokens. see my answer.

Comment: it seems from scenario 5 here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ that I can get a token that won't expire, but it worth the try.

Comment: @luschn: This seems to be a new development to me, the old blogposts said they expire at 60 days at most (to be specific, it said nothing specifically about pages) and when tested with the debugger tool around the migration they was expiring too. Good to know. (all hail for the non-wiki-so-no-diffs documentation :P)

Comment: extended user access tokens live for 60 days maximum, but he wants/needs a page access token > if you get one while using an extended user token, you get a page token that lives forever. that´s not really new, it´s like that sind many months :)

Comment: forget about blog posts, they are doomed to be outdated sooner or later. the facebook docs are pretty good and offer almost everything you need to know: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to authorize the User, that´s how you get a User Access Token:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Don´t forget to add the "manage_pages" permission in the scope Parameter. You will also have to use the Function "setExtendedAccessToken" of the PHP SDK to extend the User Token. After that, you will get a Page Access Token that is valid forever with the */me/accounts* endpoint.

If you used getLoginUrl already, then there´s something wrong with that code, you may want to add it to the question.

Before getting the accounts (with /me/accounts, not with your id), get the User ID:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

If you got a valid User Token, your ID will be in the $user Variable.

Comment: I don't wan't the user to login, I need to I need to post offline. and the authurizing code it too big to post in a comment,   $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=user_likes,read_requests,publish_actions,read_friendlists,email,read_stream,publish_stream,email,publish_actions,user_online_presence,friends_online_presence,manage_pages,publish_stream,read_mailbox,read_page_mailboxes,read_stream,xmpp_login,create_event,rsvp_event,read_friendlists"; and keep going from there :)

Comment: in order to post offline, you have to get a user access token first. for that, you have to authorize the user (in that case, yourself). just as i answered. but why wqould you post that auth code in a comment? i said "question", not "comment" ;)

Comment: anyway, you do NOT have a user token. You can easily test this, see "Usage" on the php sdk page: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk.

Comment: Please debug your code and use "/me/accounts" instead of "$user_admin_id"

Answer (score 1):

maybe this one? https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/  also see [Getting long-lived access token with setExtendedAccessToken() returns short lived token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196958/getting-long-lived-access-token-with-setextendedaccesstoken-returns-short-live)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is... you need to get a user access token to access your page tokens

Comment: if the app has the manage_pages permission, why should the user be online to get his access token?

Comment: not the app has manage_pages permission, but the user has to authorize your app with the manage_pages permission

Comment: which is already done, I'm the app owner and the page admin, and I gave my user (the page admin) the manage_page permission for the app.

Comment: and how did you do that? i created an answer, you may want to take a look at that.